# The hottest part of the day

Tags: climate-change, climate

I have lived nearly my entire life in the same home. It appears to me, the hottest part of the day is getting a bit latter in the day. I tired doing a google search, but I did not see any links that would support this idea. Also, I do not have any hard data to back up my claim.

I am thinking there is more CO<sub>2</sub> in the atmosphere now, so it takes more time for the sun to heat it up and therefore the hottest part of the day is latter.

Here are some links that I have looked at:
[Own your weather](https://ownyourweather.com/hottest-and-coldest-time-of-the-day/)
[Air Density](https://airdensityonline.com/2017/02/hottest-a-couple-hours-after-noon/)
[nbc5weather](https://nbc5weather.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/what-is-the-hottest-time-of-the-day/)

Am I right about any/all of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not as simple as this, as the temperature is not related just with the CO2 or sun radiation but: some other gases, moisture, wind, cloud presence...

One thing is the real dry temperature, that you can get from a weather station and another subject is "feels-like" temperature, that takes in account water pressure, wind... It is more close to what you can feel as temperature.

For the real dry temperature, main actor is sun radiation, as soon as you get more radiation, you are increasing temperature as all the gases at the atmosphere become excited by radiation. As soon as you reduce radiation, temperature is becoming low.

I recomend you to check by yourself. There are some more "free" webpages when you can get weather data as solar radiation and temperature and check how they are changing along the day. I used [this link](https://www.visualcrossing.com/weather-data) to get data from different places at different latittudes, as solar radiation, on the same days, varies in value and time.

Case 1: Paris 2023-05-19 to 2023-05-26

[image: Paris 2023-05-19 to 2023-05-26]

In this case, as soon as you are getting radiation, you are increasing temperature. Highest temperature has just 30 minutes delay from highest solar radiation. If you pay attention to feels-lie temperature, delay is different. That is why you feel that the hottest hours are a few hours after maximum radiation.

Case 2: Singapore 2023-05-19 to 2023-05-26

[image: Singapore 2023-05-19 to 2023-05-26]

In this case, as it is an area that it is almost constantly cloudy with high humidity, temperature is varying just a little bit, and except the first day of the period, it seems that there is no relationship. In fact, on the second day there was a storm (I am living now at Singapore) and it is reflected in a quick change in temperature (both) and solar radiation.

Conclusion: It is not as simple as it seems.

Hope it helps!